# fsolve returns an unnecessary warning when solving a simple algebraic equation

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

Using `fsolve` , I want to find the `x` for which `f(x)=0` in the case `f` is given by

```
y=1.
def f(x):
    return ((x-y)**2-y**2)**2
```

As we can see, the function has a minimum for `x=0`, and for that value we have precisely `f(x=0)=0`. 
When I try to solve with `fsolve` it returns a value that is close enough to zero, but also a warning:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
y=1
def f(x):
    return ((x-y)**2-y**2)**2

print fsolve(f,x0=0.001,xtol=1e-6)
```

The output is

```
RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the 
  improvement from the last ten iterations.
  warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)
[1.55543489e-16]
```

So, the result is satisfactory, but how can I avoid the warning and why does it return it, considering that it also provides a decent result?

Comment: What is the warning?

Comment: RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the 
  improvement from the last ten iterations.
  warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)

Comment: @3sm1r, include the warning in the question.

Comment: if you are really interested in digging, you may consider looking at the source code, at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/minpack.py and https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/minpack/hybrd.f